# Race condition: One thread creates static object, another thread uses it before it is finished initializing. How to handle?

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, race-condition, thread-local

I have several places in my code where a function static object is created once, and then used (copied) any time that function is called. One of these functions can be called from any thread. The function doesn't access any shared state other than this static object.

When thread 1 calls the function for the first time, the object is created and initialized. However, (by a stroke of luck) I have a repeatable case where the program switches to thread 2 and calls the same function before initialization is finished. The object is assigned, and used, with bad data!

I'm not sure how to handle this. I'm using critical sections in the initialization code, but that's not even the problem. This object is being used before being initialized in the first place.

I tried making this thread local using  __declspec(thread), but that doesn't work for objects, apparently.

I could just surround the whole thing with a critical section, and maybe that's the best solution, but I'm concerned about problems like this cropping up in other parts of the code- it'd be nice to have a general solution.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem once after switching from MSVC to Intel. Our solution was to remove statics where possible and in all other casses ensure that the first access to a function that contains a static variable is wrapped in a critical section. Note that it's not enough that the constructor of the variable is static, but the access to the function - which leads to the initialization of the variable - has to be atomic. Obviously this leads to a certain kind of code smell as you have to ensure that every "first call" to a function is atomic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows you could use the [InitOnceExecuteOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683493%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API. More details can be found in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/08/10151258.aspx) Raymond Chen post. Also look at the more generic [std::call_once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)

Comment: That thing is actually standard and is called `std::call_once`

Comment: Thanks @bamboon added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use a semaphore on the object, setting the semaphore to be already set to 1 when the object is created, and then decrementing it to zero when the object is initialized (and ready for use).

Just need to keep an eye out for resource starvation though.